# Wordpress: Custom post type segregation on Category page

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I've got two custom post types, for example 'Cars' and 'Bikes'. I've used Wordpress's default category to categorise the posts from the two post types. Let's say for example the categories are 'Red', 'Blue' and 'Black'.

What I'm trying to achieve here is that when I go to the category page for 'Red', I want to see the 'Cars' and the 'Bikes' that are categorised under 'Red'. I'm using the category.php and this is the query that I'm trying to run:

```
$car_args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                    'orderby'          => 'date',
                    'order'            => 'DESC',
                    'post_type'        => 'cars',
                    'post_status'      => 'publish',
                    'cat'              => $cat
                );

                // The Query
                $car_query = new WP_Query( $car_args );

                // The Loop
                if ( $car_query ->have_posts() ) {
                echo "<h3>Cars</h3>";
                    while ( $car_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $car_query->the_post();
                        echo get_post_type() . '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() . '</a><br />';
                    }
                } else {
                    // no posts found
                }

$bikes_args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                    'orderby'          => 'date',
                    'order'            => 'DESC',
                    'post_type'        => 'bikes',
                    'post_status'      => 'publish',
                    'cat'              => $cat
                );

                // The Query
                $bikes_query = new WP_Query( $bikes_args );

                // The Loop
                if ( $bikes_query ->have_posts() ) {
                echo "<h3>Bikes</h3>";
                    while ( $bikes_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $bikes_query->the_post();
                        echo get_post_type() . '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() . '</a><br />';
                    }
                } else {
                    // no posts found
                }

                /* Restore original Post Data */
                wp_reset_postdata();
```

The $cat in the query gets the category id of 'Red' category. Both these queries are correctly restricting the posts by the 'Red' category but posts from both the 'Cars' post type and 'Bikes' post type are showing up even though I've tried to restrict by post type. I've read in a few articles that Wordpress ignores the post type args on the category page. Is this true and if it is, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Drop you custom query, go back to the default loop, and then use `pre_get_posts` to set your post type and custom posts per page to your category archive page

Comment: Hi @PieterGoosen. Thanks, will try that. But if I do it this way, will I have to have category-{colour}.php for every colour that I have in the categories?

Comment: Nope, just one categoty.php will be fine

Comment: I'm busy on another question, so just give me an hour or so :-)

Comment: No problem. :) I will try and figure this out in the meanwhile.

Comment: Ok. I'm getting fried in the brain and I don't think I'm thinking clearly on this. My custom post types are showing up on the category page but what I'm trying to do is to segregate each post type into a container on the category page. For eg, the category page for Red would first have a section for a list of red cars and then in a section under that, a list of red bikes. This is why I had used a custom query. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: See my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is possible with one query only, and only with the main query without any custom queries.

First of all, lets first add your custom post types to your category page. By default, custom pist types are excluded from category pages. So we need to add this manually to the main query arguments via `pre_get_posts`. Add the following to your functions.php: (*CAVEAT: Untested and also requires PHP 5.3+*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_category() ) {
        $q->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'cars', 'bikes' ) ); // Change this according to your post types
        $q->set( 'nopaging', true ); // This will get all posts, same as posts_per_page=-1
    }
});
```

You should now have all posts from a clicked category is your set post types on your category pages.

Next, wee need to sort out your loops. Delete all your custom queries in category.php and replace it with the default loop. As you would want two block ordered by post type, we will use `rewind_posts()` so we can run the loop twice

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        if ( $post->post_type == 'cars' ) { //Change accordingly to only show cars in this loop

            // Your loop

        }
    }

    rewind_posts();

    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        if ( $post->post_type == 'bikes' ) { // Change accordingly to only show bikes

            // Your loop

        }
    }
}
```

This should now display your posts in two block sorted by post type

Comment: You sir, you're a genius. :D Initial testing shows this is exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Hi @Pieter Goosen, I've been using this on my project till now and its working great. I've now been trying to add a taxonomy parameter to the if ($post->post_type == 'bikes') but haven't been getting any success. Would you be able to help?

Comment: You will need to look into `has_term` or `has_category` or `has_tag` according to your needs

Comment: I did if( $post->post_type == 'cars' && $post->post_type == has_term(20,'location')) and this works. Thanks! This is the right way to do it, right?

Comment: When you do get some time, could you please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949435/modify-category-archive-page-loop-on-functions-php This is what I'm really trying to do. Since has_term works, I can get rid of the array_merge but functions.php still won't know what loop I'm trying to modify. @Pieter Goosen